# Matlab xml parsing delivers empty elements

Tags: xml, matlab, xml-parsing

I have a xml file with the following structure

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='us-ascii'?>

<config_Paramters name="Model">
  <joint name = "number_1">
    <parameter>
      <joint param = "MINNUMBER1"   value = "-1*M_PI/180" units = "in rad" desc = "Max ang 1"/>
      <joint param = "MAXNUMBER1"   value = "-2*M_PI/180" units = "in rad" desc = "Min ang 1"/>
    </parameter>
  </joint>
  <joint name = "number_2">
    <parameter>
      <joint param = "MINNUMBER2"   value = "1*M_PI/180" units = "in rad" desc = "Max ang 2"/>
      <joint param = "MAXNUMBER2"   value = "0*M_PI/180" units = "in rad" desc = "Min ang 2" />
    </parameter>
  </joint>
</config_Paramters>
```

And I would like to access the nodes, but the following code returns empty elements:

```
filename = 'settings.xml';
xDoc = xmlread(filename);
nodeList = xDoc.getElementsByTagName('joint');
firstNode = nodeList.item(0)
firstNodeContent = firstNode.getTextContent
```

Shouldn't this one work? Would be great if someone could tell me the problem.

Comment: Down-voters: what is wrong with this question (even before the edit)? It seems fine to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you have no text content inside your `'joint'` nodes, just other nodes, so `.getTextContent` returns nothing. Text content would look something like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='us-ascii'?>

<config_Paramters name="Model">
  <joint name = "number_1">
    Hello
  </joint>
  <joint name = "number_2">
    World!
  </joint>
</config_Paramters>
```

If you're going to structure your XML as in your question, you'll need to continue extracting individual nodes and attributes as needed. You might also be interested in various solution on MathWorks' File Exchange that convert an XML file to a Matlab `struct`, e.g., [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/48499-xml2struct) and [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28518-xml2struct) – both called `xml2struct`. If you have the Bioinformatics toolbox, there is also a little-documented function of this name included with that.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your linked FileExchange functions work perfectly. Unfortunately I can't vote the answer up by now.